# LED indicators intensity standards

Tags: led, light, tv, router

I am trying to find any resources on the LED parameters (i.e. preferred intensity and luminosity ranges) that are used as indicators in various home appliances, such as Networked devices (i.e. routers) or TV sets. The general concern I have is to have indicators that do not pollute light and are not aggressive to the eye, but I am trying to find any numbers that can be used to describe this functionality. I would appreciate all feedback.

Comment: I think looking into the amount of lumen, milicandela (mcd), lux and the viewing angle is appropriate for your application. Some suppliers will give the luminous intensity in mcd and provide a view angle. Maybe look for a warm temperature colors, with low luminous intensity and the preffered viewing angle?

Edit: Trying to find a suitable explaination but it seems to be in Dutch. I think the pictures will tell you enough.

[link](https://www.razorlux.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/lux-vs-candela.jpg)

I can't really provide any numbers, but I hope this helps!

Comment: if you look at your automobile dashboard at night, you may find that the high beam indicator is the most annoying and that it is probably blue

Answer (score 1):

ICNIRP have updated their hazard assessment of LEDs for 2020 in [this statement](https://www.icnirp.org/cms/upload/publications/ICNIRPled2020.pdf) and there are exposure guidelines in [this document](https://www.icnirp.org/cms/upload/publications/ICNIRPVisible_Infrared2013.pdf) which seems comprehensive and could point you to product safety standards.

Comment: Those are maximum exposure limits before you'll do actual damage to someone's eyes, which is why the doses are very high (kilowatts per m^2 per sr).  While he should definitely stay under those limits for safety reasons, they aren't really helpful for deciding how bright an indicator light that will probably be many thousands of times dimmer than the MPE.

Answer (score 1):

Such "official" resource may be hard to find because it depends too much on the situations where and when the indicators are used.
It's always better to test yourself in real life than relying on a table written by someone who had a completely different idea than yours. If you want a LED light to be strong or weak, you make am experiment and check if it's good.

Standard LED used for indicators are technically limited to 20 mA. This is the technical upper limit. But you should use this only if you really want a strong light output, to make it visible from far away and high ambiant light conditions. For example, outdoor, under the summer sun.

Indoor you can divide the intensity by 5 or 10 depending on how much light there is in the room, for the same visual effect. And in the dark you can divide it by 20 or 40. It means if you put 0.5 mA, your LED will still be enough visible in a completely dark room.

It depends very much on where the indicator will be used.
The most annoying place can be sleeping rooms. In cars, indicators, especially the blue "high lights" one, are often too strong and disturb nightly driving.
Yet the same light may be almost unnoticeable in the day light.

If you are concerned about that, the smart way is to control the intensity by routing the LED supply through resistors depending on the situation to achieve intensity smart control.

It also depends where the LED will be positioned: On the side of a box, or straight in front of your eyes?

And when and why the LED has to be observed: Is it only intended for the repair guy, once in ten years, if ever, or is it something that factory workers have to keep an eye on 24/7?

LED colour is also very important: Most agressive are green and blue. Warm colours like red and orange are soft to the eyes despite that red symbolises danger and green is the symbol of nature.
This is because the visual impact of a colour on a surface (eg. the colour of a paint) is opposite to the impact of the colour of a light.
A red marking will catch your attention more than a blue one. But a blue indicator light will be more present than a a red one.

White is very neutral visually and a good choice, too often discarded because we think colour is cool stuff. In fact white is quite "design" if you ask me.

And finally, you have the energy concern. In many case you will use only 2 mA just to save power. When you have 50 LEDs on a panel working 24/7, it makes a difference after one year.